# The name does not refer to any table in Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I deleted the custom log table and rebuild the table with same naming by collection API.

Success to see detail of custom fields.
[image]

Can not found the table in query. This is Error message below:

```
The name 'COGNOS_REPORT_OP_CL' does not refer to any known column, table, variable or function.
```

Do I have to wait for hours or days if rebuild the table?

Comment: The initial data from a new custom log may take up to an hour to display in Azure Monitor, according to Azure documentation. From the point where you defined the custom log, it will begin collecting entries from the logs found in the path you specified. The entries you uploaded during the custom log creation process will be not retained, but it will collect existing entries in the log files it locates.

Comment: here is the document  [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs#step-5-validate-that-the-custom-logs-are-being-collected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs#step-5-validate-that-the-custom-logs-are-being-collected "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs#step-5-validate-that-the-custom-logs-are-being-collected")

Comment: @SuryasriKamini-MT, your two comments are the correct answer. Please post them as an answer (and not as comments), so that the post's author would be able to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the MSFT documentation, it takes up to an hour to display the initial data from a new custom log in Azure Monitor. It will start collecting entries from the logs found in the path you provided,  once you define the custom log.
The entries that you uploaded during the custom log creation process will be not retained, but it will collect existing entries in the log files it locates.
Please refer this documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs#step-5-validate-that-the-custom-logs-are-being-collected